# Exception thrown: write access violation. prev_ptr was 0x4

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I am learning about linked lists, and I decided to try implementing linked lists in C++ on my own.

I made a `Node` class with attributes `int val` and `Node* ptr`.
Then I made a `Linked_list` class with the attribute `first_node`, and the constructor functions work.

The `append()` function 'appends' a node to the list (like in Python). I first thought of just making `ptr` a reference to the node's pointer and then changing it when its null, but references once made, can't be changed to refer to any other variable, so I made another variable `prev_ptr` that points to the `Node`'s pointer (which makes it a `Node**`).

Every loop, it checks if `ptr` is NULL, if not, `ptr` and `prev_ptr` get updated to the next `Node`'s pointer value, and the address of the next `Node`'s pointer value, respectively.

This keeps happening until it finds a null pointer, and then changes it to the inputted node's address.

But I'm getting an error saying:

> Exception thrown: write access violation. prev_ptr was 0x4.

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Classes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

class Node {
    public:
        int val;
        Node* ptr = nullptr;
        Node(int Val = NULL) {
            val = Val;
        }
};

class Linked_list {
    public:
        Node first_node;
        Linked_list(int F) {
            Node f(F);
            first_node = f;
        }
        void append(Node& element) {
            Node* ptr = first_node.ptr;
            Node** prev_ptr = &first_node.ptr;
            while (true) {
                if (ptr == nullptr) {
                    *prev_ptr = &element;
                    break;
                }
                ptr = (*ptr).ptr;
                prev_ptr = &((*ptr).ptr);
            }
        }
};
```

main()

```cpp
int main() {
    Linked_list list(5);
    Node three(3);
    list.append(three);
    Node four(4);
    list.append(four);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the program with a debugger. Keep an eye out for where the bad address comes from. This is almost always faster than asking a SO question.

Comment: Hint: when you update `prev_ptr`, remember that you already updated `ptr` right before it.

Comment: Nodes should be invisible to the user. I want to add `int`s to a list. not create a node on the stack and then add the node to my list.

Comment: Note: Instead of `(*ptr)./*something*/` you can use `ptr->/*something*/`.

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself an unnecessary variable and use the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor): `Linked_list(int F): first_node(F) { }`. Note this is a really weird way to do a linked list. You've made it impossible to have an empty list. This design decision may come back and cause problems later.

Comment: @sweenish  I initially tried doing that, but when I created the Node inside the function, it was local and got deleted after it got executed

Comment: Your Node should be privately declared in your list class. When I mean invisible, I mean users shouldn't ever know that an intermediate Node class is being used.

Comment: @sweenish but how do I declare a Node inside append() that is local to the class but not local to append()?

Comment: @G.Sliepen , oh shit, I noticed the mistake now, can't believe that this was the bug **facepalm**

Comment: To answer your last question to me, I posted an answer with an example Linked List class I keep around for SO.

Comment: @HaydenSoares linked list nodes are typically allocated *dynamically(, such as with `new`. That will solve your issue with creating `Node` variables locally. You just have to `delete` them when you are done using them, ie in the list class's destructor and assignment operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            ptr = (*ptr).ptr;
            prev_ptr = &((*ptr).ptr);
```

First you advance `ptr` to the next node. Then, you use `ptr` again forgetting that it has already been advanced: `(*ptr).ptr` now points two nodes forward, and we don't know if we can go that much far.

Perhaps you need to swap the assignments.

```
            prev_ptr = &((*ptr).ptr);
            ptr = (*ptr).ptr;
```

(Further, why not `ptr->ptr`?)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you're doing a few things in an odd fashion. First, your Linked_List should probably NOT have a Node for firstNode. It should have a Node *. After all, an empty list is possible. So is (normally) deleting the first node. Also, there's an informal naming convention of calling it `head`. There's also a standard convention of calling the link in your Node `next` rather than `ptr`.

But there are two simpler methods for your append() method. First, you can also keep a Node * tail in Linked_List. This is common. It points to the last node in the list. If you do that, then append looks like:

```
void append(Node &nodeToAppend) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = &nodeToAppend;
        tail = &nodeToAppend;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = nodeToAppend;
        tail = &nodeToAppend;
    }
}
```

However, it's also worthwhile to be able to insert anywhere or append without a tail:

```
 void append(Node &nodeToAppend) {
     if (head == nullptr) {
         head = &nodeToAppend;
     }
     else {
         Node *ptr = head;
         while (ptr->next != nullptr) {
              ptr = ptr->next;
         }
         ptr->next = &nodeToAppend;
     }
 }
```

An insert in some sort of sorted order would be nearly identical, although slightly different. The while-loop would look like:

```
         while (ptr->next != nullptr && ptr->value < nodeToAppend.value) ...
```

but would otherwise be identical.

Comment: Regarding the unconventional names and implementation, I only knew that linked lists contain nodes that contain a value and a pointer to the next node before doing this. Is it considered bad practice to attempt implementing something before knowing how it is actually implemented?

Comment: @HaydenSoares Nope. I was just trying to help you improve and follow conventions you're not expected to know at your level.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't solve your immediate issue, but answers a question raised in the comments.

Linked lists are usually (where I taught) a 300-400 level assignment. There are a lot of principles that one must be competent in to write a decent linked list. First, I'll show the `main.cpp` and its output.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "list.hpp"
#include <iostream>

template <typename Container>
void print(Container& container, std::ostream& sout = std::cout)
{
    for (auto i : container) {
        sout << i << ' ';
    }
    sout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    List<int> list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }
    print(list);

    list.erase(list.find(4));
    print(list);
    list.erase(list.find(1));
    print(list);
    list.erase(list.find(10));
    print(list);
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 3 5 6 7 8 9
```

It doesn't test every aspect of the linked list, but it serves to demonstrate what a user should be expected to work with. Users will want to interact directly with the list and its iterators in C++. You create a `Node`, and then add the `Node` to your list. That's a level of DIY that no user wants to be bothered with. In the code below, you'll see that a `Node` is still used, but it only exists within the `List` class. Users will never see a `Node`.

You can look in functions like `push_back()` (similar to your append) for specific answers related to your question.

To explain it a bit more, the pointers are key. Yes, I declare a local `Node*` that will go out of scope, but the object created continues to exist on the heap. And the list is able to keep track of these `Node`s due to how linked lists work, namely that the `Node`s know where their neighbors live (hold their addresses).

There is also a `List<T>::iterator` class. In the declaration, functions marked as `// minimum` are required if you want to use your linked list in a range-based for loop. The other functions do work toward satisfying the requirements of [*`LegacyBidirectionalIterator`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator); this is the level of iterator used by `std::list` in the C++ Standard Library.

The code below should only be considered a decent example (Hopefully not too presumptuous on my part). It is lacking some functionality that's found in `std::list`, and likely does a few things in non-optimal manners. A big thing that will need tweaking is removing the member function `find()` and make the class work with `std::find()`.

**list.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef MY_LIST_HPP
#define MY_LIST_HPP

#include <algorithm>  // std::swap
#include <cstddef>  // std::size_t

/*
 * Pre-declare template class and friends
 */

template <typename T>
class List;

template <typename T>
void swap(List<T>& lhs, List<T>& rhs);

/*
 * List Class Declaration
 */
template <typename T>
class List {
 public:
  List() = default;
  List(T val);
  List(const List& other);
  List(List&& other);
  ~List();

  void push_front(T val);
  void push_back(T val);

  class iterator;
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
  iterator find(T val);

  std::size_t size() const;

  iterator erase(iterator toErase);  // Implement
  void clear();
  bool operator=(List other);
  friend void swap<T>(List& lhs, List& rhs);

 private:
  struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(T val) : data(val) {}
  };

  Node* m_head = nullptr;
  Node* m_tail = nullptr;
  std::size_t m_size = 0;

  // Helper functions
  void make_first_node(T val);
  Node* find_node(T val);
};

/*
 * List Iterator Declaration
 */
template <typename T>
class List<T>::iterator {
 public:
  iterator() = default;
  iterator(List<T>::Node* node);  // minimum
  T& operator*();                 // minimum
  iterator& operator++();         // minimum
  iterator operator++(int);
  iterator& operator--();
  iterator operator--(int);
  bool operator==(const iterator& other);  // minimum
  bool operator!=(const iterator& other);  // minimum
 private:
  Node* m_pos = nullptr;
};

/*
 * List Implementation
 */
template <typename T>
List<T>::List(T val) : m_head(new Node(val)), m_tail(m_head), m_size(1) {}

template <typename T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& other) {
  m_head = new Node((other.m_head)->data);
  m_tail = m_head;
  m_size = 1;

  Node* walker = (other.m_head)->next;
  while (walker) {
    push_back(walker->data);
    ++m_size;
    walker = walker->next;
  }
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::List(List&& other) : List() {
  swap(*this, other);
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::~List() {
  clear();
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::push_front(T val)
{
  if (!m_head) {
    make_first_node(val);
    return;
  }

  Node* tmp = new Node(val);
  tmp->next = m_head;
  m_head->prev = tmp;
  m_head = tmp;
  ++m_size;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(T val) {
  if (!m_head) {
    make_first_node(val);
    return;
  }

  Node* tmp = new Node(val);
  tmp->prev = m_tail;
  m_tail->next = tmp;
  m_tail = tmp;
  ++m_size;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin() {
  return iterator(m_head);
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end() {
  return iterator(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(T val) {
  return iterator(find_node(val));
}

template <typename T>
std::size_t List<T>::size() const {
  return m_size;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(typename List<T>::iterator toErase)
{
  Node* node = find_node(*toErase);

  if (node->prev) {
    node->prev->next = node->next;
  } else {
    m_head = node->next;
  }

  if (node->next) {
    node->next->prev = node->prev;
  } else {
    m_tail = node->prev;
  }

  Node* toReturn = node->next;
  delete node;

  return toReturn;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {
  Node* tmp = m_head;
  while (m_head) {
    m_head = m_head->next;
    delete tmp;
    tmp = m_head;
  }
  m_tail = nullptr;
  m_size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::operator=(List other) {
  swap(*this, other);

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::make_first_node(T val) {
  m_head = new Node(val);
  m_tail = m_head;
  m_size = 1;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Node* List<T>::find_node(T val) {
  if (!m_head) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  Node* walker = m_head;
  while (walker != nullptr && walker->data != val) {
    walker = walker->next;
  }

  return walker;
}

template <typename T>
void swap(List<T>& lhs, List<T>& rhs) {
  using std::swap;

  swap(lhs.m_head, rhs.m_head);
  swap(lhs.m_tail, rhs.m_tail);
  swap(lhs.m_size, rhs.m_size);
}

/*
 * List Iterator Implementation
 */
template <typename T>
List<T>::iterator::iterator(Node* node) : m_pos(node) {}

template <typename T>
T& List<T>::iterator::operator*() {
  return m_pos->data;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator& List<T>::iterator::operator++() {
  m_pos = m_pos->next;

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::iterator::operator++(int) {
  iterator tmp(m_pos);
  ++(*this);

  return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator& List<T>::iterator::operator--() {
  m_pos = m_pos->prev;

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::iterator::operator--(int) {
  iterator tmp(m_pos);
  --(*this);

  return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::iterator::operator==(const iterator& other) {
  return m_pos == other.m_pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::iterator::operator!=(const iterator& other) {
  return !(*this == other);
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code and explaination

I think this code should work as well, so there is no need to have two pointers. It's based on an [example of *“good taste”*](https://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux#t-850000) that Linus Torvalds gave in an interview.

```
void append(Node &element)
{
    Node** cursor = &first_node.ptr;
    while ((*cursor) != nullptr)
        cursor = &(*cursor)->ptr;
    *cursor = &element;
}
```

It eliminates the need for multiple pointers, it eliminates edge cases and it allows us to evaluate the condition of the while loop without having to let go of the pointer that points to the next element. This allows us to modify the pointer that points to `NULL` and to get away with a single iterator as opposed to `ptr` and `prev_ptr`.

### Naming conventions

Also the norm is to call the first node in the linked list `head` and to call the pointer to the next node `next` instead of `ptr`, so I will rename them in the following code.

```
void append(Node &new)
{
    Node** cursor = &head.next;
    while ((*cursor) != nullptr)
        cursor = &(*cursor)->next;
    *cursor = &new;
}
```

Comment: Totally agree. Much better approach, but as a SO answer it needs a bit of meat explaining what you're doing and why. Otherwise people will come along and copy it without really understanding what it does and how it works. World has enough [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @user4581301 You're absolutely right! I have now explained my code and fixed a few problems. I've also tested it and it seems to work.

Comment: A bit of extra explanation on the "Why it works": Taking a pointer to `ptr` allows you to combine the insertion point (previously the `prev_ptr` with the current pointer . This also abstracts away all of the differences between pointer that serve the same purpose but have different names like `head` and `ptr` and can eliminate a lot of redundant code that handles the different names.